# How to remap json key-value mapping in javascript/ typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, mapping, key-value

Given

```
{"a": {"name": "king", "firstname": "Thomas"},"b": {"age": "21"}}
```

I´m trying to figure out a simple way converting it to

```
{"name": "king","firstname": "Thomas","age": "21"}
```

In Javascript/ Angular. Maybe someone has a goode idea, I would be very thankful.
I´m trying to change a response to make it suitable for an API request.

Edit: I changed the question, I forgot to mention, that I have multiple key-values pairs in the second level.

What I´m trying to achieve is getting rid of the first level keys in a json-file because the API I´m sending it to doesn´t have those, it just uses the key in the second level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.  I added a third property to the object to show you what happens if you have two objects with the same property (the one that is iterated later overwrites the one that comes before, but since you can't rely on property order in an object this could produce unexpected results).  If none of your properties are duplicated then no worries.

```js
var data = {"a": {"name": "thomas"},"b": {"age": "21"},"c": {"age": "22"}};

// "c" will overwrite "b"
var converted = Object.keys(data).reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, data[e]), {});
// Object.keys(data) gives the array [“a”, “b”, “c”]
// Reduce that array to an object by assigning, to a new empty object,
// the properties of the objects found in each property of data

console.log(converted);
```

Comment: What I´m trying to achieve is getting rid of the first level keys in a  json-file because the API I´m sending it to doesn´t have those, it just uses the key in the second level

Comment: Could you maybe briefly explain what your code is doing ?

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like:

```
const original = {"a": {"name": "thomas"},"b": {"age": "21"}}
const result = Object.values(original)
```

Or, if you need a bit more flexibility:

```
const original = {"a": {"name": "thomas"},"b": {"age": "21"}}
const result = []
Object.keys(original).forEach( key => result.push(original[key]) )
```

warm regards

Comment: Please take a look at:  
https://typescript-v5ptkv.stackblitz.io

For me it worked. Only "Object.values" is not working with every browser.

Comment: I changed the question, I forgot to mention, that I have multiple key-values pairs in the second level. But thank you very much for your anwser !